Ubuntu 22.04 in VirtualBox Unresponsive: Need Troubleshooting Help
I have Ubuntu 22.04 installed on my MacBook Pro laptop using VirtualBox. I followed a YouTube tutorial and successfully installed Ubuntu, but now, when I start the VM, it's unresponsive. I can't click on any of the applications.
Does anyone have suggestions on how to troubleshoot or resolve this issue?


Does the mouse move inside the VM Guest?

Yes. I also checked on the bottom right corner of the VM guest and see that the mouse and keyboard pointers have been captured.

How much memory did you allocate to the Guest VM?

6 Gigabytes for memory.

My macbook pro is old. Its a 2012. Has intel core i7, 16 GB of RAM, and 500 GB of storage.

And how much video memory?

@nobody I have a NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M with 1024 MB and
Intel HD Graphics 4000 with 1536 MB.

I meant how much Video memory gave you your vm?

It seems that the system gave it 16mb

Give it more and try again.

It worked! I maxed out the memory to 128MB.
